# Is it appropriate to convert a project to a different language and keep the same versioning?

Tags: version-control, versioning, semantic-versioning

Say there's a package, `foo`. Foo is being developed primarily in Python, up until version `1.13.2`. At that point in time, the primary developer decides that Go is much better suited to the task. He creates a new branch and codes up a package in Go that has the same functionality or even some improvements to `1.13.2` of the Python version.

Following semantic versioning, is it appropriate for him to merge this into development, bumping the major version, as `2.0.0`?

Comment: Did the public API change?

Comment: @RubberDuck Probably not. If it's a project end-users will use, then maybe some differences. If not, then it's less likely. It depends on what the project is to be honest. Let's just assume the public API does **not** change.

Comment: If the public API does not change (i.e. previous consumers can update to the new version without any code breaking), then it should be a minor version. How or with what languages the project is implemented should have no bearing on the semantic versioning. For instance, Python packages are frequently rewritten into C for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [semver.org](http://semver.org)

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> - MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> - MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
> - PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
> - Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.

What you're describing is build metadata.

> Build metadata MAY be denoted by appending a plus sign and a series of dot separated identifiers immediately following the patch or pre-release version. Identifiers MUST comprise only ASCII alphanumerics and hyphen [0-9A-Za-z-]. Identifiers MUST NOT be empty. Build metadata SHOULD be ignored when determining version precedence. Thus two versions that differ only in the build metadata, have the same precedence. Examples: 1.0.0-alpha+001, 1.0.0+20130313144700, 1.0.0-beta+exp.sha.5114f85.

Following MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH-prerelease+BUILDMETADATA and since you didn't mention any prerelease status:

1.13.2+Go

If instead he switched to 2.0.0 I would expect it to be a breaking change that meant I would have to rewrite my stuff to make it work because of incompatible API changes.  If that isn't true you're losing customers for no good reason.

Comment: It's just such a shame you didn't convert sooner.  I'd have downloaded 1.2.3+Go. :)